# Download Csv with PHP

Tags: php

I do not know why but I have tried all the codes in the different sites and they have not worked to me, the file does not download I do not know why I am using this code and it does not download either, the file is created successfully but it does not download I mean there is not any error.

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=result_file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

$data = array(
 array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
 array('123', '456', '789'),
 array('aaa', 'bbb')
);

$output = fopen("php://output", "w");
foreach ($data as $row) {
    fputcsv($output, $row);
}
fclose($output);
```

I wonder what is wrong?

My header:

[image: header]

Comment: Check the log to make sure you're not getting a "headers already sent" warning.

Comment: Your English isn't very clear. Is it creating `result_file.csv` or not?

Comment: I am creating result_file.csv, and it is in public file, and that code should force to download that file, but it does not force to download I wonder why does it not download?

Comment: See my first comment.

Comment: Yes I checked and I do not get any error or warning, and the file exists

Comment: Then I don't see a problem. Does it show the CSV file in the browser window?

Comment: exactly @Barmar

Comment: Use the Network tab to see the headers that are being sent.

Comment: I attached a picture of the header

Comment: That's the request header, I meant the response header. Make sure it has all the headers you put in `header()` calls.

Comment: I changed the pic

Comment: How are you accessing the PHP script? Are you using AJAX instead of linking to the URL?

Comment: I use vue.js with laravel maybe the vue.js is not allowing the download?